# How to assign different IP address for mail server and file hosting

Tags: domain, hosting

I have a simple question. We had managed a site with their mails. Now they have shifted their mail server to different agent company. But domain and file are still with my company.

When they configured the mails are sending and receiving correctly. But the site is down. They gave me the control panel username and password. When i search in that they gave the different IP address. When i change it, the mail won't work, but the web site will.

How can i point website to my address and mail to their site?

Comment: You should change the MX record to point to the new mailserver, while keeping the A record for the domain pointing at your server.

Comment: as per @JennyD says you have to set the correct MX record to point the IP address of the new mail server. This can be done quite easy, but the procedure on how to do depends on who is the service you use to register the Domain;

Comment: Hi when i add the ip address in MX record, I'm getting this error message "You must specify a fully qualified domain name."

Comment: MX records must point to a hostname, not an IP address.

Comment: Okey Michael... Now its point to a hostname....that is vera.in. I created an 'A' record with this hostname and pointing to a ip address '2.2.2.2.' (sample ip address) If I gave like this, customer can login their mail browser and he can send and receive the mail. But the site is not working. If i change the ip address to '4.4.4.4' (sample ip address), customer cant login their mail browser and he can't send and receive the mail. But site  will work. How can I gave this two function should be working?